# sometimes serial write operation blocks after initializing

Tags: serial-port, embedded-linux

I have my embedded linux box with 2 serial ports application, which tests all serial ports with wrap cable (only Rx connected to Tx, no other pins).
The second (non-console) port works fine.
The first (console) port sometimes works, but sometimes does inexplainable things.
To test the first channel I kill running 'getty' before opening it. The respawn is also forbidden.
Then I do the following:

```
    system("killall getty");
    Sleep(1000);
    if ((fd = open(Name, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NONBLOCK)) <= 0)
    MsgFatal("Serial '%s' open error %d.", Name, errno);
    BRN = B115200;
    tcgetattr(fd, &Opts);
    cfsetispeed(&Opts, BRN);
    cfsetospeed(&Opts, BRN);
    cfmakeraw(&Opts);
    Opts.c_cflag |= PARENB;
    Opts.c_cflag |= PARODD;
    Opts.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;
    Opts.c_cflag &= ~CRTSCTS;    /* no HW flow control */
    Opts.c_cflag |= CLOCAL | CREAD;
    tcsetattr(fd,TCSANOW,&Opts));
```

After this, SOMETIMES (I mean on some run of the application) the next write operation blocks!

Any advice will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Using `cfmakeraw()` and specifying odd parity is rather unconventional (but that wouldn't affect whether writes block or not). By "wrap cable" you probably mean loopback? Does `MsgFatal()` really do what its name implies? What library does that routine come from (4 pages of google results turn up nothing), or is that your own code? You should be checking the return codes from all syscalls such as `tcgetattr()` and `tcsetattr()`.

Comment: Thanks. I rechecked both with no parity and even - the same exactly. BTW, please, why is it unconventional?
MsgFatal is my logger routine, which prints message and quits the application.
had return codes checking, but it was always zero. But for now I returned and rechecked - all returns were zero.

Comment: Parity checking will produce a false positive for a 2-bit error.  But parity errors are actually rare; usually it only indicates a misconfiguration rather than character corruption. `cfmakeraw()` is most often used for non-text data employing a binary protocol.  The message packet is usually validated with a packet checksum, which is more likely to detect errors.  A strong checksum like CRC32 covering the whole packet can make parity superfluous.  Note that IEEE 802.3 (Ethernet) frames do not use parity.

Comment: The random success or failure suggests that there is a race condition, presumably with `getty` releasing the serial port.  Try the `open()` without O_NONBLOCK, and then use `fcntl()` to get and then set O_NONBLOCK.  Note that Linux man page mentions that *"the O_NONBLOCK flag indicates that one wants to open but does not necessarily have the intention to read or write."*

Comment: I do not know if this may be considered as an answer, therefore I put this as a comment meanwhile...

I noted, that my debug prints are feed to the ttyS0 when running from flash - logical! This is not the case when running from NFS and telnet/gdb, which blocks on writes, but this is obviously incorrect - I said to myself. And inserted fclose(stdout) into ttyS0 initialization code.
From now on I can't get into blocking write neither from flash nor from NFS/telnet.
So, the problem seems to be solved, although I do not understand how and why.

Comment: I was too fast!
It does not work again - again the first write unexpectedly blocks.
And I did nothing for this, just rerun it again while debugging the other piece of code...:-((((

Comment: Running days of tests shows:

1. system("killall getty") hangs the application, if the loopback is closed. Otherwise, everything works fine when I close the loopback after system starts and stabilizes.

2. If I do not kill getty, and start with loopoback closed, the first write hangs. Again, if I start and stabilize without loopback and insert it later - everything works fine.

I will be very thankfull for any hint/help!!!

Answer (score 0):

First off, the death of a `getty` process should immediately be reaped by its parent, either `init` or an aspect of `BusyBox`, and relaunched.  How long it takes can vary, but it is usually pretty quick.  But that shouldn't affect writing to the port.

How do you know the write is blocking?  Please show that code.

Comment: This seems like only a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: Thanks, wallyk. I removed "respawn" in inittab. I also see that I can't login after the application runs. Is it not enough?

About blocking write: I put printf around the write operation. Also run application in debugger (remote debug via Ethernet).

Again, there are some inexaplainable cases when all runs as expected! I send test message and reads it back properly for tens of minutes. BUt some starts blocks on the first write.
The code is more than simple:
        write(fd, TEST_STR, sizeof(TEST_STR));

Comment: @leonp:  what happens between the `tcsetattr()` (at the end of the code shown) and the `write()`?  Is there enough delay for the changed setting to take effect?  Are there any other mode changes?

Comment: @wallyk: I think - yes. There is the second ttyS1 initialized, then some time passes till everything starts... I think some 50-100ms passed...
Besides, when the application enters this state (write blocks) I rerun it under debugger several times with break-point before 'write', then one step - write, which never ends.